# The constant sheaf and skyscrapers over $\mathbb P^{1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be the constant sheaf on $\mathbb P^{1}$ and $\mathcal O_{x}$ the structure sheaf.

Why can we say that $K/O_{x}$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of all the skyscraper sheaves $K/\mathcal O_{X,x}$ at $x$?

This is mentioned in passing at 
http://www.leuschke.org/uploads/SnowbirdTalks.pdf
on page 127, and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not true. Just compare the global sections. But the formulation in the link

> The quotient sheaf $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O}_X$ can be thought of **(stalkwise)**
>   as the direct sum over all $x \in X$ of the skyscraper sheaf $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, so is flasque.

is correct (but also a little bit misleading, as you see). I would suggest a direct computation which shows that $\mathcal{K} / \mathcal{O}_X$ is flasque.